# WPF Control Library Target .NET Core 3 or .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I'm porting my WPF application from .NET Framework to .NET Core 3. I got this generic UI library that is published on NuGet, that is currently targeting .NET Framework v4.6.1. Now, if I just change the target to .NET Core 3, then it won't work anymore in .NET Framework projects. .NET Standard is designed to solve this kind of problem but I don't think it will help in the case of WPF projects.

What's the right thing to do here? Publish and manage 2 separate packages?

Then this library has 2 other derived libraries. If I create 2 separate packages for the base library, that means I'd have to publish and manage 2 of each derived libraries as well. This solution stinks. Got anything better?

Comment: .NET Core 3.0 adds support for WPF which was previously not available, and it also supports .NET Standard 2.1. Theoretically, if you target your code for .NET Standard 2.1, it should work both in .NET Core as well as .NET Framework.

But since WPF support in .NET Core is new, I guess it would be difficult to say how it turns out without getting your hands dirty with it.

Comment: If I target .NET Standard 2.1 I can't get the WPF framework added into the project

Comment: Ahh!!! I forgot to mention, WPF in .NET Core is supported only on the Windows platform, so it cannot be part of the .NET Standard. I guess the only option left for you is to maintain 2 code bases.

Comment: Note that .net 5 is intended to bring the two frameworks together into one. November 2020 seems a long way off but maybe you could consider living with .net old until then. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WPF application that targets .NET Core 3 may actually reference and consume a control library or NuGet package that targets .NET Framework 4.6.1.

You shouldn't have to do anything with the control library itself for this to work, assuming you don't use any APIs that is not present in .NET Core because then you will eventually get runtime errors.

Try to add a reference to the DLL or install the NuGet package as usual. It should work even if the NuGet package only contains a single assembly in `lib\net461`.

Comment: You're right; it just displays warnings but works (most of the time?). I'm having all kind of other compatibility problems so I don't think it's worth rushing to migrate yet.